# Conduit combining pipe and wire

Tags: electrical, plumbing, conduit

I need to run a 1/2" black pipe for gas and about 4 electrical cables, on average 12/2 AWG through a 12" thick brick wall. Can I do it in a single tube of conduit and what should I use? Is just DWV PVC pipe okay or should I get something like 2" electrical conduit?

Comment: With the accented e showing up at the end of your question, it seems you may not be from the US. I believe most of our more common answerers are going to come at this from a US-centric perspective, so it would be very helpful if you indicated where in the world you are located. There may be code variations that impact what you can and must do.

Comment: I'm in the US, that was auto incorrect. Who else uses inches, please?

Comment: What other country uses AWG (AMERICAN wire gauge)?

Comment: Valid points. Odd auto-co-wreck. My apologies. Specifying locale is still important as code may vary from state to state.

Comment: Mid Atlantic somewhere

Comment: Inches - UK at least many of the older generations, India...

Comment: All the great countries of the world use inches.  Liberia, Burma, ... okay, I got nothin'.

Comment: Yes but only one of those great countries has seen the invention of pipe... LOL

Comment: Why do you want to run this outer tube at all?

Comment: To make it clean and prevent the surrounding brick from crumbling and crushing in